# Can we determine the polarization of a neutrino?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, polarization, neutrinos, chirality, helicity

I recently read that neutrinos have a polarization property---their polarization is opposite to antineutrinos.

Is it possible to determine the polarization of a neutrino? For example, we can determine the polarization of a photon using a polarizing beamsplitter, V-polarizations will be reflected into detector A, and H-polarized photons will pass through into detector B.

Can we do something similar with neutrinos, something like a neutrino beamsplitter? (Of course, neutrino detectors are huge, but in theory?)

Comment: The right term for this degree of freedom is called helicity.

Comment: As I understand it, given they're nonzero both in mass and spin they also have a nonzero magnetic moment. If memory serves its on the order of $10^{-19}$ that of the electron. So yes you could in theory measure such a quantity